# Symfony : multiple record insert?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have one Object `$items` . In that Object have **1000 record**.. I use **Bulk Insert in Symfony**, If i let `$batch_size = 40` then it will save 1000 record 10 to 15 seconds. But i want save 1000 record save about 1 second. Do you have any ideas, please help me, thanks!

```
                            $batchSize = 40;
                            $i = 1;
                            foreach ($items as $item) {
                                if (!empty($item->getstatus())) {
                                    $message = 'Success';
                                    $intel = $modelIntel->getEntity();
                                    $intel->setNumber($item->getNumber());
                                    $intel->setMessage($message);
                                    $intel->setModelName($item->getModelName());
                                    $em->persist($intel);
                                    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
                                        $em->flush();
                                        $em->clear();
                                    }
                                    ++$i;
                                }
                            }
                            $em->flush();
                            $em->clear();
```

Comment: What happens with `$batchSize = 1000;`?

Comment: Thank @Arleign Hix . I have also tried $batchSize = 1000. But it's still very slow.